# How to convert an integer to a string in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the heading 'Region' is represented by integers 1 to 4. I am trying to change 'Region' from data type int64 to a string I have tried using `.astype(str)` and `.apply(str)` but I still receive the error:

*File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Region'*

Sample of data frame:

[image]

If I use the Region2 column the my code works but that means each month I have to convert all the region numbers to the name of the region and that will be time consuming

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# creating a data frame 
df = pd.read_csv("CSVData2.csv") 

#Change region to string

df['Region'] = df['Region'].apply(str) # I have tried both of these.
df['Region'] = df['Region'].astype(str)


df_out = pd.crosstab(df['Region'], df['Sales'], margins = True, margins_name = 'Total')


df_out.to_excel(r'/users/python/documents/DataFrametest.xlsx', sheet_name='Rawdata', index = True)
```

Comment: have you made sure that "CSVData2.csv" actually contains **Region** as column?

Comment: add a sample from that *CSVData2.csv* file to the post, like header and some row (can be made up, but lookalike rows, if you data is under  confidentiality)

Comment: Meanwhile, it is better to specify column types during parsing (via the `dtype` parameter of `pd.read_csv`) than converting after the dataframe is read.

Comment: If your CSV has Region heading then `astype(str)` should work.

Comment: @mrzo Definitely a column with Heading Region

Comment: `File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: 'Region'` tells you that pandas cannot find a column with the name *Region*. Can you provide us the output of `print(df.columns)`? Sometimes something goes wrong during reading the dataframe from the csv file.

Comment: @mrzo A noob error when I checked name in the Region in the file that somehow there was a space behind Region. Removed the space and it worked. Thanks all for pointing me the right direction.

Comment: Happens to all of us :)